# Square instead of colon in between time on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, fonts, time

Why does the time on my laptop (bottom right_ show a square instead of a colon?  Something to do with a font?  Can anyone tell me simply how to resolve it - I'm not a whizz with settings though know how to adjust fonts in control panel or settings if required.

Answer (score 0):

Which font are you using?

As far as I recall, the clock uses the ratio character U+2236 (∶) instead of the colon: (:)

If you're using Segoe UI Black, your font is missing U+2236. If you chose a font with that character, or used the default font, then you should be able to correct it.
Segoe UI or Segoe Semi-Light should do it, for instance.

Comment: How do I correct it please?

Comment: Try using the section about halfway down the page at https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10 to revert to the original settings.